# How to import Mathematica 8 file to Maple 13?

Tags: mathematica, maple

How can I import a `.nb` file from Wolfram Mathematica to Maple? I need an example of how to integrate.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MmaTranslator/FromMmaNotebook).

- The `FromMmaNotebook(Mma_notebook_filename)` and the `convert(Mma_notebook_filename, FromMmaNotebook)` commands translate a Mathematica notebook to a Maple worksheet and saves the results to disk. These commands enable Mathematica users to automatically translate their Mathematica notebooks to Maple worksheets.
- You can also use the **Mathematica Translator** to translate Mathematica input and notebooks to Maple input and worksheets.  For more information, see the [MmaTranslator[MmaToMaple]](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MmaTranslator%2fMmaToMaple) help page.

Comment: @derdack: You're welcome. If you want, you can set this as the accepted answer by clicking the tick mark on the left. Welcome to Super User!